# Firefox displays unnecessary horizontal scrollbar when using float

Tags: html, css, firefox, scrollbar, css-float

Firefox and Chrome seem to render scrollbars differently when included in a float-right element.

As shown by the following minimal code example ([here's a codepen](https://codepen.io/digemall/pen/MWVjLWb)), Firefox renders an unnecessary horizontal scrollbar, while Chrome shows the vertical scrollbar only and simply renders the box a little wider to make room for the scrollbar itself.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-scrollable">
    <div class="entries">
      <div>1 - TEXT OF ENTRY</div>
      <div>2 - TEXT OF ENTRY</div>
      <div>3 - TEXT OF ENTRY</div>
      <div>4 - TEXT OF ENTRY</div>
      <div>5 - TEXT OF ENTRY</div>
      <div>6 - TEXT OF ENTRY</div>
      <div>7 - TEXT OF ENTRY</div>
      <div>8 - TEXT OF ENTRY</div>
      <div>9 - TEXT OF ENTRY</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  float: right;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 90px;
}
.container-scrollable {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
.entries {
  white-space: nowrap;
  /*margin-right: 20px;*/
}
```

Some screenshots:

- Firefox (102) on windows 10:
  [image: Firefox 102 rendering win10]
- Firefox (98) on Ubuntu 20.04:
  [image: Firefox 98 rendering ubuntu 20.04]
- Firefox (102) on Ubuntu 20.04:
  (horizontal scrollbar is missing, the vertical bar appears only on mouse over but covers part of the text)
  [image: Firefox 102 rendering ubuntu 20.04]
- Chrome (103) both on Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10:
  [image: Chrome rendering]

Any suggestion ?

Comment: there is no hoizontal scroll on my FireFox (linux). you also may use `overflow: hidden visible;`

Comment: @MisterJojo Setting `overflow-y:hidden` would only prevent the text from being readable... I get the same problem on Firefox for Windows. The width of .entries seems to be calculated before the scrollbar is added, thus the scrollbar is shown over it. Sadly I didn't find a quick fix for this...

Comment: @MisterJojo: I've added some screenshots. Indeed with FF102 on ubuntu, the horizontal scrollbar does not appear, but the vertical scrollbar covers the text when appears (I honestly don't know, maybe this is expected by a scrollbar that appears only on mouseover).

Comment: Yes, on my Firefox (linux debian KDE) the scrollbar only appears on mousehover or keyboard scrolling. It is over the text. Otherwise it is hidden.

If you absolutely want to control this visual, you will have to code your own scrollbar. [There are also libraries](https://github.com/search?q=custom+scrollbar&type=Repositories)

Comment: @MisterJojo: I know I can replace the scrollbars with custom ones, but this seems a firefox misbehavior (bug?) to me. In particular on windows, where scrollbars are always visible an this makes the horizontal scrollbar to appear

Comment: the list of bugs in chrome is also very long, yet they have more human resources to fix them

Comment: @MisterJojo: yes I'm aware of that, mine wasn't a criticism towards FF. I just wanted to be sure if there's something wrong with my html/css or if there's a workaround to solve this

Comment: The wysiwyg consistency issues between systems or even between software are always complex to resolve. This is often related to problems rendering fonts, Adobe never having disclosed its algorithms for drawing them, There are fewer problems with Typescript fonts